# freebsd 8.0 release won't boot after upgrade - can't find kernel

Tags: freebsd, kernel

What would be the simplest method of repair; upgrade via disk, single user mode using disk? Thanks.

Comment: Is this a "kernel won't boot" problem, or a "Blows up somewhere in the rc sequence" problem?

Answer (score 2):

this page may help

http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/kernelconfig-trouble.html

"The kernel does not boot:" section

you should be able to boot of the old kernel that worked but freebsd only keeps one copy so be careful.

from here you will be able to fix what is broken. I guess you did not use the default kernel options and have removed something that is needed by your server

EDIT:

or instead of moving the kernel you could just load the old kernel like so

```
unload kernel
boot /boot/kernel.old/kernel
```